# Angularfire2 Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angularfire2

On my app i'm setting an auth service. Pretty simple behavior.

appComponent contains a simple button for login through Google with event `(click)='login'`. After i accept, I want to redirect my user to `/account`.

The app works as expected **BUT** i encounter an error on `ng serve`:

> [default] C:\Project\src\app\app.component.ts:24:8
>
> ```
>  Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.
> ```
>
> [default] C:\Project\src\app\services\auth.service.ts:28:22

These errors appears to be non blocking, since the app appears to work properly. **Do you have any idea of how to solve them?**

**I guess** the problem seems to appear because i apply then on the returned _auth.login() result which is the angularfire auth login method WHICH returns a promise... But i don't know how i can refactor my code to call the service properly if it's indeed the problem. I think (correct me if I'm wrong) it's a bad idea to call redirect from the service itself.

Here are my files.

app.component.ts:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private _auth: AuthService) {
    this.date = new Date();
}

login() {
    this._auth.login()
    .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/account']);
    });
}

logout() {
    this._auth.logout()
    .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    });
}
```

My AuthService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders } from 'angularfire2';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    user = {};
    isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
        this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
        if (user && !user.auth.isAnonymous) {
            this.user = user;
            this.isAuthenticated = true;
            console.log('User Logged in', user, this.getUserEmail());
        } else {
            this.user = {};
            this.isAuthenticated = false;
            console.log('User Not Authenticated', user);
        }
        });
    }

    getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    getUserEmail() {
        return this.user.auth.email;
    }

    login() {
        return this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google
        });
    }

    logout() {
        return this.af.auth.logout();
    }
}
```

**Do you have any example of an authservice using AF properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularFire2's `logout` method [doesn't return a Promise](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.6/src/auth/auth.ts#L122-L124):

```
public logout(): void {
  this._authBackend.unauth();
}
```

There is an [unmerged PR](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/684) to have `logout` return a Promise, but at the moment, it doesn't.

You could either change your `app.component.ts` code to:

```
logout() {
    this._auth.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

Or you could change your `AuthService` to:

```
logout() {
    this.af.auth.logout();
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Either way, you will need to watch to see if/when the PR is merged.

Comment: Thanks! So much time about a so small mistake! I should have look more carefully my IDE...